# Clingy or something else?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I need an adjective to describe a person who would do anything for another person they love. For instance, they would buy everything for someone they love, they would dance for them, they would do anything whatever is asked even if those things would embarrass them or make them look silly. The best I could find is "clingy", but I'm not sure whether it's correct or not. It's probably similar to "to be a simp", but that's an internet slang, in my view. I'm looking for a proper English word that can be used casually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Clingy' implies that a person is hopelessly dependent on another. It is really the opposite of being willing to do anything for the other.

If you mean that this willingness to please the other person a positive trait, consider using:

- Devoted
- Dedicated
- Selfless
- Self-sacrificing
- Unselfish

If you think that this is a negative trait, you might be trying to say they are:

- Desperate
- Attention-seeking
- Simpering
- Sentimental
- (Too) eager to please

Comment: When I hear people say 'I'm a people-pleaser' I begin to suspect that they have either been in therapy, or have read one or more emotional self-help books.

Comment: If psych jargon is acceptable, "codependent" fits the bill - it's broadly negative and also strongly implies you've been in therapy/reading self-help books.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, that's why I've gone for adjectives rather than nouns, which would just be labels in this case.

Comment: @Ottie 'Codependent' can mean having an unhealthy attachment to someone, but it can also imply that both have a problem and that there is enabling behaviour, such as a relationship between two alcoholics. I would be wary of using that.